# who to fill detail input base on child window popup

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have a parent window for entry transaction that havs customer ID field input. User have to click find button beside it and new window will be opened and user can findout there. Whenever user choose selected customer, the parent will display some information of the customer like name, address may be, and detail of claim. Anybody can show me the link about the case? Or suggest me the outline? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var $parent = $(window.opener.document); //or parent.document.body
$parent.find("#name").val("xxx").end()
       .find("#address").val("yyy");
window.close();
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please flag it as answered so others can find the help too